# Sum Javascript variables (strings, actually)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three `div` that contain a number.

```
<div class="a">10</div> 
<div class="b">20</div>
<div class="c">30</div>
```

I get the number inside each one with jQuery `.html()`.

```
var val_1 = $('.a').html(), 
    val_2 = $('.b').html(),
    val_3 = $('.c').html();
```

How can I sum them?

This do not work as expected:

```
var total = val_1 + val_2 + val_3;
```

Since returned 102030, when I expected 60.

Comment: You are concatenating Strings.

Comment: Your variables are strings.  You need to convert them to ints.  `var val_1 = parseInt($('.a').html(), 10);`  In JavaScript, `+` is *both* addition and string concatenation ("addition").

Comment: Also, this is not a matter of jQuery, but a matter of JavaScript in general.

Comment: Will you only have one instance of each of the elements?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, since you want only the content of your divs, you'd better use `$('.x').text()` instead of `$('.x').html()`.

Now what's happening is that you're additioning strings, ie concatening them: `'1' + '2' + '3soleil' === '123soleil'`.

You want to parse them into numbers, which is done with

```
Number(val1) + Number(val2) + Number(val3)
```

If you know they're integers, you can more safely use `Number.parseInt(val, 10)` (the second variable of that function, called radix, is the mathematic base of your number. It's most likely a decimal number (10), but could be hexadecimal (16), boolean number (2), etc)

Comment: If you're going to suggest `parseInt()` *don't forget the radix*.

Comment: Only answer to prefer `.text()` over `.html()`, only answer to prefer `Number()` over `parseInt()`. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/SxAR7/)***

You could group them, use each to iterate, and total their parseInt numbers

```
var val = 0;
$('.a, .b, .c').each(function(){
 val += parseInt(this.innerHTML,10);
});
alert(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) because your div content is evaluate as string:

```
var val_1 = parseInt($('.a').html(),10), 
    val_2 = parseInt($('.b').html(),10),
    val_3 = parseInt($('.c').html(),10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt()` on each variable; right now it's treating them as strings and concatenating them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string value returned from .html() as an int using parseInt().

```
var val_1 = parseInt($('.a').html())
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you don't want to type (var + var), you could do the following.

**Firstly, the issue in your code was that your variables were interpreted as strings, we can force the INT data-type like, so.**

```
val_1 = parseInt($('.a').html()), 
val_2 = parseInt($('.b').html()),
val_3 = parseInt($('.c').html());
```

**Then we aggregate the variables into a tidy array, then perform the `.reduce()` function, which is a sum function.**

```
var aggregate = array(val_1, val_2, val_3);
aggregate.reduce(function(a,b){return a + b})
```